# Change class to div in alternative layout of Joomla template if module position sidebar is empty or not

Tags: php, joomla

I'm creating an alternative layout for articles view in my Joomla Template. I would like to load a modules (sidebar) inside the component area and assign a different class to the divs that contains main and sidebar according to the presence or not of modules in the sidebar.

How could I write the code? I've tryed something like this but doesn't work:

```
<?php
    $modules =& JModuleHelper::getModules('sidebar');
    if($modules != 0)
    {
        $secclassl = 'l-sec col-md-8';
        $secclassr = 'l-sec col-md-4';
    }
    else
    {
        $secclassl = 'l-sec col-md-12';
    }
?>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: There are examples of this if you just google or look in the templates that are included in the core distribution.  There is an API to cut the modules in a position, make sure you check using ACL since there may be modules for some people but not for others..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved myself this way:

```
<?php
    if($modules =& JModuleHelper::getModules('sidebar'))
    {
        $secclassl = 'l-sec col-md-8';
        $secclassr = 'r-sec col-md-4';
    }
    else
    {
        $secclassl = 'l-sec col-md-12';
    }
?>
```